# Python - How to show a transparent image in a window?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to display an image that already has a transparent background into a window. Currently I'm using OpenCV `cv2.imshow` which doesn't show the alpha channel and that results in the pixels being black. Are there any other library or different kinds of approach that shows an image with a transparent background in a window with the background desktop screen showing?

Original Image:

[image]

Current result:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: cv2.imshow ignores transparency. You can use matplotlib's imshow. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Comment: @FarhoodET Matplotlib's imshow could be used if we want to make the image transparent by having a four channel image or by using the `alpha` argument. But I don't think that we could make the window or the canvas transparent.

Comment: Try Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick. Imagemagick can display transparent images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python standard library **Tkinter** to show an image in a transparent window.

*Code Snippet:*

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage, NW

root = Tk()

root.attributes('-transparentcolor','#f0f0f0')

# Canvas
canvas = Canvas(root, width=450, height=600)
canvas.pack()

# Image
img = PhotoImage(file="./images/panda.png")

# Positioning the Image inside the canvas
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=img)

# Starts the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this makes the whole window transparent including my panda friend, I would like to display the original png as shown in the 'desired result' image.

Comment: @Vamsi Well, try adding `root.attributes('-transparentcolor','#f0f0f0')`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks, that seems to work, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @CoolCloud Thank you, works like a charm. I just want to ask if there's any other library that's able to do this other than tkinter?

Comment: @Vamsi I am not sure about other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it works with qt on linux [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416368/display-an-image-with-transparency-and-no-background-or-window-in-python)
It's looks like u don't really need `Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground`
Use `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` to make frames disappear.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QMainWindow()

window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
# window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
# window.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

label = QLabel(window)
pixmap = QPixmap('po.png')
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
label.setGeometry(10, 10, pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

window.label = label

window.resize(pixmap.width(),pixmap.height())

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: po]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the answer. None other than this solution was working on linux.